# How to draw a blurred circle in opencv Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to draw multiple circle on a specific image, There is a way to draw them blurred?

example:

```
cv2.circle(img,center,20,color,-1)
```

is possible to draw that circle blurred?

Comment: There is no build-in function to achieve this. You would need your own function that draws a blurred circle. E.g. you can draw a circle on a grayscale map, blur the image and then use it as a gradual mask to blend the circle color onto your image using `numpy`. Does this help or do you need a code example?

Comment: Could you provide me with an example code?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my final solution.
First, create a mask image drawing a white circle at the point location on a black image.

Then blur the whole image.

Finally copy blurred content to the original image only where mask is > 0

```
mask_img = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype='uint8')
cv2.circle(mask_img,center,20,color,-1)

img_all_blurred = cv2.medianBlur(img, 99)
img = np.where(mask_img > 0, img_all_blurred, img)
```

Comment: So you were asking for a circle of blurred image with sharp contour and not a blurred circle of a given colour?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the explanation if it was not clear

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in-built in OpenCV but you can get creative. [Have a look at alpha blending](https://learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

```
# create black background
background = np.zeros((450,450,3), np.uint8)

# initialize the mask of same shape but single channel
mask = np.zeros((450,450), np.uint8)

# draw a circle onto the mask and apply Gaussian blur
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (250, 250), 30, (255,255,255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (17,17),7 )

# for blending purpose create 3-channel mask of float datatype
alpha = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)/255.0

# create a colored image
colored = np.zeros(background.shape, np.uint8)
colored[:,:,:] = [200, 10,200]

# perform alpha-blending and convert to integer
blended = cv2.convertScaleAbs(background*(1-alpha) + colored*alpha)
```

**Result:**

[image]